# Check if a CSV string contains a given value C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, csv

I'm reading a comma-delimited list of numeric ids which is stored as a string. I need to check whether an id already exists within that list. For example:

"1,2,3"

If I check for "2" I should find it, but if I check for "22" I should not.

What's the most straight-forward and concise way to do this?

My current code is as follows:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("wishlist");
if (cookie != null)
{
     var JSONstring = cookie.Value; //Cookie stored as JSON
     Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>> jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<dynamic>>>(JSONstring); 

     // Retreive only the nodeId of each item and store it in a CSV list
     string umbracoCSV = String.Join(",", jObj.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.nodeId));

     // Convert the CSV into an IEnumerable list of ints
     IEnumerable<int> umbracoNodeIdList = umbracoCSV.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse); 

     foreach(int umbracoNodeId in umbracoNodeIdList){
         if(umbracoNodeId == 2){
              // Do code if it matches
         }else{
              // Do code if it doesn't match
         }
     } 
}
```

As you can see this code includes a pretty unneccessary loop and really I want to be able to parse the CSV string directly for the value rather than performing a nested loop (as this loop will be nested in another if this is not possible).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify your code using `Any` method:

```
bool isExists = umbracoCSV.Split(',').Any(x => x == "2");

if(isExists) { }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a fast and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here:

- find `2` in the string

  ```
  if(umbracoCSV.Contains(",2,") //,2, is to rule out 22
      //Do something
  ```
- use a regular expression instead of the `String.Contains`
- split the string and use `Any` on it

  ```
  var toArray = umbracoCSV.Split(',');
  if(toArray.Any(x => x == "2")
      //Do something
  ```
- if u still make it an `IEnumerable<int>`, you can also use `Any`

  ```
  if(umbracoNodeIdList.Any(x => x == 2)
      //Do something
  ```